# Angular 7: Can't bind to 'directive' since it isn't a known property of 'element'

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom directive and I get this error:

[image]

The directive is included in declarations inside @NgModule. Nonetheless is not working. If you need more information on the error just ask. I don't know what's going on.

app.component.html

```
<input class="text" [appInputFormat]>
```

input-format.directive.ts

```
[![import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputFormat]'
})
export class InputFormatDirective {

    constructor(){};

  @HostListener('focus')  onFocus(){
    console.log('on Focus');
  }
  @HostListener('blur')  onBlur(){
    console.log('on Blur');
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';



import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CourseComponent } from './course/course.component';
import { FavoriteComponent } from './favorite/favorite.component';
import { PanelComponent } from './panel/panel.component';
import { LikeButtonComponent } from './like-button/like-button.component';
import { LikeCountComponent } from './like-count/like-count.component';
import { DirectivesComponent } from './directives/directives.component';
import { HiddenComponent } from './hidden/hidden.component';
import { SwitchcaseComponent } from './switchcase/switchcase.component';
import { ForComponent } from './for/for.component';
import { TrackbyComponent } from './trackby/trackby.component';
import { IfComponent } from './if/if.component';
import { StyleComponent } from './style/style.component';
import { TransopComponent } from './transop/transop.component';
import { InputFormatDirective } from './input-format.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CourseComponent,
    FavoriteComponent,
    PanelComponent,
    LikeButtonComponent,
    LikeCountComponent,
    DirectivesComponent,
    HiddenComponent,
    SwitchcaseComponent,
    ForComponent,
    TrackbyComponent,
    IfComponent,
    StyleComponent,
    TransopComponent, 
    InputFormatDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking at the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

This type of selector:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputFormat]'
})
```

Builds an *attribute* directive.

> It's the brackets ([]) that make it an attribute selector.

So it has to be used as an attribute like this:

```
<input class="text" appInputFormat>
```

Brackets when you define the *selector*, but no brackets in the Html when you use the directive.

Comment: you do use brackets in the selector if the directive also declares an input of the same name

Comment: Doesn't `<input class="text" [appInputFormat]>` attempt to *bind* the attribute? I don't understand your comment? Are you referring to an `Input` property? Then yes, if you have an `Input` property then you can bind. But I saw no `Input` property in the OP code?

Answer (score 4):

proper syntax is:

```
<input class="text" appInputFormat>
```

You put things in brackets when they're accepting an input, as in if you also declared an input of the same name on the directive, similarly you can use parens if you declare an output of the same name.